# Taller Active tab for static navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I was studying how to make static navigation bars and managed to get up to this

https://jsfiddle.net/dm310tau/

```css
.bottom-bar
{
 list-style-type:  none;
 margin:           0;
 padding:          0;
 overflow:         hidden;

 position:         fixed;
 z-index:          100;
 bottom:           10px;
 left:             0;
 width:            100%;
 height:           35px;
 color:            #999999;
 background-color: #101010;
}

.bottom-bar li
{
 float: left;
}

.bottom-bar a
{
 display:         block;
 color:           #999999;
 text-align:      center;
 font-size:       medium;
 padding:         6px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border:          1px solid transparent;
}

.bottom-bar a:hover:not(.active)
{
 color:  #EFEFEF;
 border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

.bottom-bar .active
{
 color:            #FEFEFE;
 background-color: #303030;
 padding:          3px 16px 8px 16px;
 border:           1px solid #EEEEEE;
}

.bottom-bar .active:after
{
}
```

```html
<ul class = "bottom-bar">
 <li class = "bottom-link">
  <a class = "active"
     href = "/one">
   One
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class = "bottom-link">
  <a href = "/two">
   Two
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class = "bottom-link">
  <a href = "/three">
   Three
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

As the next step I was trying to make it so that active bar ends up a little bit taller like so,
[image: Like so]
However, I am not sure where is the first place to look for something like this. I have explored option of using
`.bottom-bar .active:after`, but, unfortunately, because the bar is supposed to be static, I can not make the part pop up a little bit higher by using a border like I have seen it done on other websites.

I do understand that I can do a few of these using Bootstrap, but that is not my intention. I would like to learn CSS instead of just using what's there and not understanding what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Chrome at least. The comments explain what is happening.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   #footer {
     width: 100%;
     height: 35px;
     background-color: black;
     position: fixed;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;

     padding: 5px 0 0 20px; //top right bottom left
   }

   .link {
     color: gray;
     margin-right: 10px;
     padding: 5px;
     float: left;
     position: relative;
   }

   .active {
     color: white;
     height: 50px;
     border-bottom: none;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
   }

   .active:after { /*or :before*/
     content: ""; /*allows shape to display*/
     display: block;
     width: 100%; /*cover element*/
     
     top: -20px; /*position as you would like, just to show the difference*/
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     height: 60px;
     border: 1px solid white;
     border-radius: 5px;
     background-color: black; 
     z-index: -1; /*place behind element*/
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="footer">
   <div id="links">
    <div class="link active">Contact</div>
    <div class="link">About</div>
    <div class="link">Support me!</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you plan on attaching the active class to the clicked element without JS? Or you just wanted an all CSS approach for making the active class?

Comment: Easy, I generate html on server side, and server will know which one to make active depending on the requested link. This way I do not need js to do any of the work, and I never even have to bother using js

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to work on chrome and edge which is what I needed